# Specify related string field in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Django 1.11, Django Rest Framework 3.6.

I have 2 models, `Foo` and `Bar`:

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField()
    sex=models.CharField()

class Bar(models.Model):
    type=models.CharField()
    foo=models.ForeignKey(Foo)
```

In my `serializers.py` I have:

```
class FooSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = ('sex',)

class BarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    foo = FooSerializer(many=False)
    class Meta:
        model = Bar
        fields = ('type', 'foo',)
```

This produces JSON like this:

```
{
  "type": "abcdefg",
  "foo": {
    "sex": "male"
  }
}
```

What I really want is for the "foo" field to be flat, i.e.:

```
{
  "type": "abcdefg",
  "foo": "male"
}
```

One possible solution would be to use the [StringRelatedField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#stringrelatedfield), but this would entail setting the `__str__` method of the `Foo` model to return the `sex` field, which I do not want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try [SerializerMethodField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield) instead of.

```
class BarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    foo = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    @staticmethod
    def get_foo(item):
        if item.foo:
           return item.foo.sex

    class Meta:
        model = Bar
        fields = ('type', 'foo',)
```

Answer (score 1):

An easier alternative is to use [SlugRelatedField](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#slugrelatedfield), which can be pointed at any field.

```
class BarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    foo = SlugRelatedField(slug_field='sex')
    class Meta:
        model = Bar
        fields = ('type', 'foo',)
```

Comment: Easier, but a bit misleading perhaps?